# Como selecionar somente os dias da semana?

Tags: sql

Como eu faço pra pegar só os dias de semana, excluindo os finais de semana, utilizando SQL?

Eu preciso notificar o cliente sobre algum débito, e se for sexta-feira eu não posso cobrá-lo porque vai se iniciar o fim de semana, ele terá sábado e domingo para pagar então ele só será notificado na segunda-feira caso não tenha efetuado o pagamento.

```
SELECT P.dtvenc, 
FROM foo P
WHERE p.dtvenc = To_date(SYSDATE)-1
```

Comment: Tente manter o código nas perguntas reduzido ao mínimo necessário para seu entendimento, ok? O código original era imenso e a maior parte nada tinha a ver com o problema.

Comment: Na verdade, Wesley, isso tem a ver com este tópico da central de ajuda: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), mas o ideal seria você fazer isso e não um editor.

Comment: ok, vou seguir o conselho !!! obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende do SGBD que você usa.

Se for SQL Server, utilize a função [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174420.aspx). Vou deixar a seu critério ler a documentação no link. A forma seria a seguinte:

```
WHERE DATEPART(p.dtvenc, 'weekday') BETWEEN 2 AND 6
```

Onde `2` e segunda-feira e `6` é sexta feira.

Se for Oracle, você recorre à forma da função [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) que recebe uma data.

```
WHERE to_char(p.dtvenc, 'D') in ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
```

**Edição:** O @Caffé chamou atenção pro fato de que o número correspondente a cada dia da semana no Oracle pode variar. Isso depende da linguagem/cultura configurada. Para mais detalhes (caso seja curioso ou tenha problemas com os números), sugiro pesquisar por [National Language Support](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NLS) (o link que o Caffé comentou).

Se for MySQL, PostgreSQL ou outro sistema... Nesse caso você espera alguém que os conheça responder aqui. Colocar a tag do banco que você utiliza na pergunta ajuda a ter respostas melhores.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Renam... vou testar esse procedimento do Oracle, no caso meu Banco e Oracle mesmo.

Comment: Renan, não deu certo, não me traz resultado algum. utilizei o
WHERE to_char(p.dtvenc) in ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6')

Comment: Para retornar o número correspondente ao dia da semana, falta o segundo parâmetro no `to_char`, assim: `... to_char(p.dtvenc, 'D') ...`. Lembrando que o número correspondente à segunda-feira pode variar conforme as configurações **NLS**, e um parâmetro extra pode ser adicionado ao `to_char` ou uma configuração de sessão pode ser realizada para garantir que o comando funcione como esperado independentemente das configurações do servidor. Veja: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NLS

Comment: Valeu, Caffé! Editei aqui :)

Comment: muito obrigado Renan consegui resolver!!

Comment: @Renan quer completar com o MySQL? função `WEEKDAY(date)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

Comment: @Everson você pode editar a minha pergunta novamente para incluir o MySQL, ou pode adicionar uma resposta e ganhar um voto meu :)